# Creating a factor from a numeric variable

Tags: r

I am quite new to R and I am having some troubles with creating factors. 
I should create a factor from a numeric variable. This factor should have three levels: dissatisfied (values 0 to 4) "neither/nor" (value5) "satisfied" (values 6 to 10).

```
lsat_factor<-factor(soep$lsat)
levels(lsat_factor)
levels(lsat_factor)[0:4] <- ("Dissatisfied")
levels(lsat_factor)[5]<-("Neither/nor")
levels(lsat_factor)[6:10]<-("Satisfied")
```

I tried this but it is definitely not working. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

I would probably just use `cut`:

```
> x <- 0:10
> cut(x = x,breaks = c(0,4,5,10),include.lowest = TRUE,
      labels = c('Dissatisfied','Either/Or','Satisfied'))
 [1] Dissatisfied Dissatisfied Dissatisfied Dissatisfied Dissatisfied Either/Or    Satisfied    Satisfied   
 [9] Satisfied    Satisfied    Satisfied   
Levels: Dissatisfied Either/Or Satisfied
```

Answer (score 0):

To collapse groups, you can use the list syntax for `levels<-`. For example

```
# test data
soep <- data.frame(lsat = letters[1:10])

lsat_factor <- factor(soep$lsat)

table(lsat_factor)
# lsat_factor
# a b c d e f g h i j 
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 

levels(lsat_factor) <- list(
    "Dissatisfied"=levels(lsat_factor)[1:4],
    "Neither/nor" = levels(lsat_factor)[5],
    "Satisfied" = levels(lsat_factor)[6:10]
)

table(lsat_factor)
# lsat_factor
# Dissatisfied  Neither/nor    Satisfied 
#            4            1            5
```

Comment: If I also want to create a factor with just two levels, identifying the respondants of soep$age that are under age 18, with the two levels "under age" and "adults" what is the best way to do it?

Comment: That seems like a different question. It appeared that your original data was categorical. I assume this new age value is numeric? You can use a simple `ifelse()` if you only have two categories, or you can use `cut()` with more. But those do assume numeric values.

Comment: Yes these are numeric values